# dateparser search function returns unexpected results

Tags: python, date, datetime, dateparser

I'm using the [`dateparser`](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) python package to search for dates in a string.

Following string provides unexpected result:

Input string:

```
Feb 12 SOME STRING TORO ON 508 . 50
```

Output result:

```
[('ON 508', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 0, 8))]
```

Expected result:

```
None
```

Code:

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates

possible_dates = search_dates("Feb 12 SOME STRING TORO ON 508 . 50", languages=['en'], settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True})

for dt in possible_dates:
    print (dt)
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how to correct this?

I've looked into setting format (cannot do that in `search_dates` function).

Answer (score 0):

It must be a bug from the dateparser version you were running.

Using **dateparser 0.7.2**:

```py
>>> from dateparser.search import search_dates
>>> search_dates("Feb 12 SOME STRING TORO ON 508 . 50")
[('Feb 12', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 12, 0, 0)), ('ON', datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 0, 0)), ('508', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 0, 8))]
```